# Cannot resolve constructor 'ValueTask(System.Threading.Tasks.Task<int>)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

My `SaveLogChangeInterceptors` inherits from `SaveChangesInterceptor`, and I want to implement `SavingChangesAsync`. However in this method, I am unsure how to return the result of `eventData.Context?.SaveChangesAsync(true, cancellationToken)`. Can anyone help me solve this problem?

```
public class SaveLogChangeInterceptors : SaveChangesInterceptor
{
    

    public override ValueTask<InterceptionResult<int>> SavingChangesAsync(DbContextEventData eventData,
        InterceptionResult<int> result,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        // some code
        var interceptionResult = eventData.Context?.SaveChangesAsync(true, cancellationToken);

       return interceptionResult; // get error
    }
}
```

the error says

> Cannot convert expression type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task?' to
> return type
> 'System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.InterceptionResult>

Comment: Look closely at what you should return: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors#the-interceptor

Comment: Error is clear, but why you call SaveChanges in interceptor? This interceptor is called before actual SaveChanges.